# WCF .svc file served as plain text in IIS7.5 .NET 4.0 - Not under Default Web Site

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-7.5, svc

**FINAL UPDATE**: It turns out this was a red-herring due to a compression issue with a DotNetNuke module. I had to add  to the PageBlaster DNN module, so this is no longer an issue.

I am deploying a WCF svc file to my [live website](http://www.pokerdiy.com) for the first time and it is rendering/served up to the browser as plain text. It works fine on my dev environment on localhost. You can see the problem here:

http://www.pokerdiy.com/test.svc

The website is running on **IIS 7.5.7600.16385** on **Windows Server 2008 R2** Version 6.1 SP1 (64 bit) in an **Integrated Application pool** with **.NET 4.0** (I am using Entity Framework 4.2).

**UPDATE:** On the live server, the site is added as a Website (ie. not under Default Web Site), whereas on my dev environment DotNetNuke is running as a Virtual Directory under the Default Web Site with it's own web.config (which I compared to the one on the live site and is identical).

Interestingly, when I am on the live server and I browse to the test.svc file in the DEfault Web Site then it works (http://localhost/Test.svc) - however, the one under the PokerDIY.com website does not (http://www.pokerdiy.com/test.svc). So it seems as though my Default Web Site is different to the additional websites somehow?

Another interesting thing: I removed all .svc Handler Mappings and now I can get the "HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found" error. So the Handler Mappings are intercepting it, it's just not doing anything with it! I can get it back to static text by re-adding the .svc Handler Mappings.

After a lot of RTFMing, The first thing I checked was the Handler Mappings as per the MS article: all the svc mappings are there (svc-integrated is at the top as [per this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752252%28v=vs.90%29.aspx))

I also re-installed WCF as per [this article](http://grekai.wordpress.com/2011/03/10/http-error-404-3not-found-in-iis-7-5/) with no difference. Using Fiddler I can see that the Content-Type is "text/html"

What else can I try?

Note: ASMX webservices, ASP.NET files etc. all work fine.

**Update**: My Hosting Provider suggested I make the directory where the service resides into a Virtual Directory, which I did not have to do on my local machine in Dev. So now it uses the Parent websites appool and at leats it is doing something - it gets a different error. This does not sound correct though - why would it not be handled by the website appool? I moved the .svc into the root (http://www.pokerdiy.com/test.svc) to remove this from the equation).

Other things I have tried:
Changing modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false" to "true" (it is **false** in my web.config)
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
[WCF in IIS 5.1 served as plain text file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5975816/wcf-in-iis-5-1-served-as-plain-text-file)
[404 when running .net 4 WCF service on IIS (no svc file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793127/404-when-running-net-4-wcf-service-on-iis-no-svc-file)

Comment: An alternative to hosting in IIS, is to self-host the WCF service in a windows service. It's really straightforward and removes IIS from the picture. That's what I do. Cheers, Tim :)

Comment: Thanks Tim, but I need to access the httpcontext and the DotNetNuke website, so I think it needs to be in IIS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have enabled the Application Server role.

Comment: I had never heard of this until now - it was not installed so I installed it as per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751518.aspx and rebooted. I also checked http://www.tellingmachine.com/post/Installing-IIS75-on-Windows-2008-R2-Server-with-IIS-6-compatibility-manually.aspx. Unfortunatrly this has had no affect and the problem remains - but I think this is on the right path?

Comment: One thing that may be related - how can I tell what version of WCF I am using? I ran the servicemodelreg -i command in the WCF 3 folder (for 64 bit) and NOT the one under the .net 4 folder. I don't know how to tell what version of WCF I am using (it's a simple test service at this stage)

Answer (score 0):

My hosting provider says that the Directory ("/framework") under the Website needs to be configured as Virtual Directory and use the parent AppPool.

When I do this the svc does seem to get processed (and I get another set of .NET errors).

However, on my dev environment, the sub folder is NOT a separate virtual directory - does it need to be?

Comment: I don't think this is correct information - my dev environment is not set up like this. To remove Subfolders from the equation I put a .svc file into the Root of the site that does not have a code-behind file - you can see it here - http://www.pokerdiy.com/test.svc   (it is not being processed and appears as text)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Directory browsing is "disabled" as well