# How to register WCF on a website other than Default Web Site with ServiceModelReg?

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5

I am trying to [fix a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8548883/wcf-svc-file-served-as-plain-text-in-iis7-5-net-4-0-not-under-default-web-si) where my wCF services will not work on my live site which runs under it's own website instead of under Default Web Site.

I am trying to run ServiceModelReg -i but for my website, not the Default. If I put -h it says that "-s:" will recursively install the components for the particular path. However, when I run "ServiceModelReg -s:W3SVC/1/root" then it says "Error: No valid options were specified..." -s does the same thing, in short it does not seem to work.

I [read here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/d46021c3-a360-4094-be70-7ed7495b3b25) that I could run it for my website instead of Defafult Web Site by incrementing the number, but it does not seem to work even with just the s.

**So the question is**: How can I run this option with -s for my website (it is called pokerdiy.com in IIS and is a sibling of the Default Web Site).

The website is running on IIS 7.5.7600.16385 on Windows Server 2008 R2 Version 6.1 SP1 (64 bit) in an Integrated Application pool with .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

servicemodelreg.exe installs at machine level not at site level. If a .svc file is not served by the non-default site, the problem lies with the settings that should have been setup through running `aspnet_regiis -i -s <your site path>`

Comment: Thanks - however, what exactly it <your site path> - I am not sure of the syntax relative to the IIS root

Comment: The sitepath is a W3SVC/1/root type of path.